# Custom query filter for Custom Post Type that is a registered taxonomy related to the current post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, meta-query

I need your help!

I need to code a custom query filter to fetch posts from a Custom Post Type that is a registered taxonomy related to the current post (which is a diferent Custom Post Type). Working in Wordpress.

Relevant plugins I'm using: CPT-UI (to handle Custom Post Types), CPTonomies (to use CPTs as Taxonomies), Snippets (to write the custom query) and Elementor Pro (to build the templates).

My custom post types are: Clients and Projects.

At the same time, Clients is a taxonomy supported by Projects. This means that, for example: If I create a new 'Project' post called "Coca-Cola's new logo", I'll be able to assign a client to the project as a taxonomy, which in this case would be a 'Client' post called "Coca-Cola".

So I'm building the **Single Project Template** and I want to show for whom it was done, displaying the client's logo and some information about it. And I'm using a posts widget to load Client posts inside the Single Project template (a loop within the loop) and **assigning a Custom Query Id to the widget** so I can filter the Clients that I want.

In the Snippets admin panel I'm working on the code, that so far it looks like this (but is not working properly):

```
add_action('elementor_pro/posts/query/projects_clients_query', function($query)
{
  
  $client = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'clients' );
  
  $meta_query[] = [
          'post_type' => 'clients',
          'p' => $client,
  ];
  $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

What's supposed to do? First, fetch the ID of the current post's Clients taxonomy. And then set a new query to fetch all Clients posts that share the previous ID.

Comment: Shared slug between a custom post type and a custom taxonomy isn't a viable nor possible option within Wordpress.

Comment: @amarinediary thanks for the reply! I understand that the plugin "CPT-onomies" I'm using makes it possible. The devolopers state that "The CPT-onomy term’s term ID is the same as the post ID." according to this: https://www.wordpresspluginfinder.com/cpt-onomies/ , am I missunderstanding it?